# Window alert message is looping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I am working on a shopping website and want to check if the item is present in the cart. If it exists, alert it's already in the cart and return `false`. If it doesn't exist add it to the cart.

I tried it like below, the code is working fine but the alert is looping.

```
$("#showBtn").focus();
msgBoxImagePath = "http://www.ournestonline.com/assets/images/";
function showMsgBox() {
    simpleCart.bind('beforeAdd', function (item) {
        if (simpleCart.has(item)) {
            alert("Already in the Cart");
            $.msgBox({
                title: "Shopping Cart",
                content: "Already in cart",
                type: "alert"
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            $.msgBox({
                title: "Shopping Cart",
                content: "Great Selection Your Item is Added to Cart Happy Shopping",
                type: "alert"
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by looped?\

Comment: Could you edit the question and add more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
return false;
```

after the closing tag of else.